# If/Else in Payload JSX

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I'm new to react and jsx... any idea as to what is wrong with my syntax in the payload here? If the `type` is `internal` I want to send `media_file`, or if `type` is `external`, I want to send `url`.

```
const createMedia = (payload) => {
const data = excludeObjNullValue({
    name: payload.name,
    content_id: payload.contentId,
    destination_id: payload.destinationId,
    task_id: payload.taskId,
    type: payload.type,
    if(type === 'internal') {
        media_file: payload.mediaFile;
    } else {
        url: payload.url;
    }
}, true);
const formData = new FormData();
for (const [k, v] of Object.entries(data)) {
    formData.append(k, v);
}
return request.postFormData('/media', formData);
};
```

Comment: What error are you getting?  Where in your component does this code live?  What does `excludeObjNullValue` do?

Answer (score 3):

You cannot use `if/else` inside object definition. You should create an object first and then use `if/else` to add properties to that.

```
let obj = {
    name: payload.name,
    content_id: payload.contentId,
    destination_id: payload.destinationId,
    task_id: payload.taskId,
    type: payload.type
}
if(type === 'internal') {
   obj.media_file = payload.mediaFile;
} else {
   obj.url = payload.url;
}
const data = excludeObjNullValue(obj, true);
```